# This always gives error of Missing $ inserted

Tags: errors

I want to write this expression: `cat /etc/passwd | cut -d ':' -f 1 | grep '.\{4,\}'` in latex. How do I do it?

I try to use following code, but it has an error.

```
\item \emph{cat} /etc/passwd $\vert$ \emph{cut} \textendash d \textquoteright $\colon$\textquoteright \space\textendash f \number1 \space $\vert$ \emph{grep} \textquoteright .$\backslash$\left\lbrace \number4, \backslash\right\rbrace $\textquoteright$
```

Comment: Since you haven't provided an MWE no real answer is possible but I guess, the [listings](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings) package is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

For typesetting source code I would recommend using the [minted package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\newminted{bash}{%
    autogobble,
    %linenos,
    %breaklines,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{bashcode}
    cat /etc/passwd | cut -d ':' -f 1 | grep '.\{4,\}'
\end{bashcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that for using minted you need python and pygments (see section 2.1 *Prerequisites* of the [minted documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf)) and you need to pass the `-shell-escape` flag to LaTeX (see section 3.1 *Preliminary*).

Answer (score 0):

`\left\lbrace` (and also `\right`...) needs math environment.

But why so strange notation? It seems as you want to write paths. Package `url` helps in such cases. For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407554/this-always-gives-error-of-missing-inserted}
\end{document}
```

Or, simply

```
\begin{verbatim}
  cat /etc/passwd | cut -d ':' -f 1 | grep '.\{4,\}'
\end{verbatim}
```

Comment: I think he wants to write a bash command, so `url` is probably not helpful.